# Checking input for a negative integer error

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm trying to make a program that will take an integer from the user and flip a coin that many times. However, when the user inputs a *negative integer*, the program experiences an 'overflow Exception.' How can i make it so that the user can only input a positive integer?

```
int newLoop = 0;
        int Number;
        string answer1 = default(string);
        string text = default(string);
        Random newNumber = new Random();
        Console.WriteLine("How many times do you want the coin to flip?\n");
        string line = Console.ReadLine();
        int value;
        if (int.TryParse(line, out value))
        {
            string[] myValues = new string[value];
            while (newLoop < value)
            {
                Number = newNumber.Next(0, 2);
                if (Number == 0)
                {
                    answer1 = "Tails\n";
                    myValues[newLoop] = "Tails";
                }
                else
                {
                    answer1 = "Heads\n";
                    myValues[newLoop] = "Heads";
                }
                text = " " + answer1;
                foreach (char u in text)
                {
                    Console.Write(u);
                }
                newLoop++;
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
            Title();
            Question();
        }
        else if (line == "")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nThat is not a valid number...");
            Console.WriteLine("Please try again:");
            Console.WriteLine("~enter to continue~");
            Console.ReadLine();
            coinTask();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nThat is not a valid number...");
            Console.WriteLine("Please try again:");
            Console.WriteLine("~enter to continue~");
            Console.ReadLine();
            coinTask();
        }
```

Comment: Just check it is bigger than zero? On which line you get overflow? Did you debug your code?

Comment: You can force your input to be positive with Math.Abs or just check if value > 0 and give an error message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the lines:

```
int value;
if (int.TryParse(line, out value))
```

to:

```
uint value;
if (uint.TryParse(line, out value))
```

That way, you are only accepting 0 and positive integers.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the value after you have parsed it:

```
if (int.TryParse(line, out value) && value >= 1)
```